# PyQt lineEdit on textEdited signal value lost after function call

Tags: python, pyqt, qcombobox, qpushbutton, qlineedit

```
#^^^^class stuff here for setting UI^^^^


# connecting combobox to slot/function get_baffle_number
   self.baffle_number_combobox.currentIndexChanged.connect(get_baffle_number)

# connecting PushButton action "clicked" to function on_click
   self.pushButton.clicked.connect(on_click)


#connecting lineEdit to slot/function get_baffle_cost
   self.baffle_cost_lineEdit.textEdited.connect(get_baffle_cost)


@pyqtSlot()
def get_baffle_cost(text):
    baffle_cost = text
    return baffle_cost


def get_baffle_number(text):
    #add 1 to the index returned by comboBox to get the number desired by user
    baffle_number = text + 1
    return baffle_number


def calc_baffle_cost():
    test_total = (get_baffle_cost() * get_baffle_number())
    return test_total


@pyqtSlot()
def on_click(self):
    baffle_cost = calc_baffle_cost()
    print(baffle_cost)
```

After I connect that `lineEdit` to the function via the `pyqtSlot()`, it seems to get the value, but immediately dumps it if I attempt to use `baffle_cost` from another function. I watch it in PyCharm during debugging and it holds it just as long as the `lineEdit` has focus it seems. Pressing the `pushButton` is right when it loses its value.

I cannot use the returned `baffle_cost` anywhere from `get_baffle_cost`.

Am I missing something? The furthest I've got is that attempting to simply print `calc_baffle_cost()` and a hexadecimal is printed. I am assuming that is a memory location, but can't be sure. (new to Python)

Sorry if this isn't enough information. I am simply attempting to take `baffle_cost` from a `lineEdit` and multiplying that by a value taken from a `comboBox`.

Comment: where do you want to place the value of `test_total`?

Comment: Also, could you indicate what the QPushButton is involved in?

Comment: The `QPushButton` is when the user is done selecting from `baffle_number_combobox` and `baffle_cost_lineEdit` which simply multiplies them. 

Well, this is what I want it to do, but I lose the values from the `baffle_cost_lineEdit` the second it loses focus.

`test_total` I would like (for now) printed `on_click`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems my problem was two-fold, or more.

I was not correctly scoping my functions and not utilizing the right namespaces. (Sorry if this terminology is incorrect. I am new to Python and PyQt.)

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):

    # sizing of widgets

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):

    # UI stuff here QlineEdits, etc.
    self.baffle_cost_lineEdit.editingFinished.connect(self.get_baffle_cost)

    def get_baffle_cost(self):
        baffle_cost = self.baffle_cost_lineEdit.text()
        return baffle_cost
```

This needed to be in the same scope(indentation) as my `retranslateUi()` function in my `Ui_MainWindow` Class like above.

I think if I had better structured my project this wouldn't have been an issue. I have definitely learned my lesson about having it all in one script. (program.py)

The other issue(s) I encountered is that the PyQt function `text()` called from a `QlineEdit` returns a `QString` and not a `str`. I simply needed to cast it to a string.

I was losing the value because the function `get_baffle_cost` wasn't properly scoped with the `baffle_cost_lineEdit`